# sqlite database outside CI app folder

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter-3

I am trying to build a multi web app with 1 sqlite database in codeigniter and I would like to put the sqlite database outside the application folder. I entered the directory of my sqlite databse but it does not work.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'sqlite:' . '/public_html/database/masterDB.sqlite',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => '',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: its a good question it helped me out as well in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just made a typo with your little ' . ' but assuming that is not the case...

Your "Paths" are relative to your document root.

Your Codeigniter runs via your index.php in your document root.
So if you are placing your database folder at the same level as your document root, then you would have.

```
/where/is/my/app/public_html/                            <<< Document Root
                             index.php
                             application/ 
                             database/masterDB.sqlite
```

So your database folder is at the same level as your index.php, using the ./ notation meaning at the same level ( whereas ../ means up a level ).

Your path of

```
'dsn'   => 'sqlite:' . '/public_html/database/masterDB.sqlite',
```

is looking for `/where/is/my/app/public_html/public_html/database/masterDB.sqlite`
,which won't exist

So you want

```
'dsn'   => 'sqlite:./database/masterDB.sqlite',
```

Answer (score 0):

its possible.

```
$db['second'] = array(
    'dsn'      => '',
    'hostname' => '',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' =>  '.././db/data.db' ,
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlite3',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt'  => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

my linux root is

/var/www/html/ci/applications

and my sqlitedb is at

/var/www/html/db/data.db folder

it works fine.

tested as working